# routerLink for multiple component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

I have anchor tag given below:

```html
<a class="uppercase" routerLink="settings/pressure"
  routerLinkActive="text-success" (click)="closeModal()"
>
  <div class="pad-btm">
    PRESSURE
  </div>
</a>
```

I want to pass another route inside **routerLink**.
When **settings/pressure** loads it will set anchor as active. Same way I want it for another route.
Thanks!

Comment: Hard to get the point. You want to load another route on click this route?

Comment: so currently routerLink="settings/pressure" .I want to assign another value to routerLink when that component(route) loads.

Comment: Any example of the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think i get it. You can do this

```
<a class="uppercase" [routerLink]="routerLinkUrl"
  routerLinkActive="text-success" (click)="closeModal()"
>
  <div class="pad-btm">
    PRESSURE
  </div>
</a>
```

And on your *.ts* file

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router:Router) { }
// default value for routerLink
routerLinkUrl = 'settings';

NgOnInit(){
//Logic to define url 
  if(this.router.active == 'foo'){
    this.routerLinkUrl = 'settings'
  }else{
    this.rounterLinkUrl = 'pressure'
  }
}
```